# Rails - Rake test and rubocop in one task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, static-analysis, rubocop

I'm trying to setup my rails project so that all the verification required by a contributor is in one command, currently we have been running:

```
rake test
```

But now we also want to use rubocop for static analysis:

```
rubocop -R -a
```

I want this to be executable in one simple rake task. It would be nice to override 'rake test' to run rubocop then the standard rake test stuff for a rails project, as then no-one will have to remember to change the command. But if I have to create a separate rake task, that's probably fine too.

I've seen the rubocop rake integration [here, at the bottom](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), but I'm not sure how to bundle that with 'rake test' into one task... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily define your own rake task which first invokes Rails' `test` rake task and then the code snippet you mentioned for rubocop.

For example, in a .rake file you could have something like that:

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

desc 'Run tests and rubocop'
task :my_test do
  Rake::Task['test'].invoke
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new  
end
```

If you feel the need to customize the call to Rubocop and that involves more code, you could create another custom task, say :rubocop, which you then invoke from :my_test as well.

Finally, an alternative to creating your own rake task and sticking with `rake test` would be to modify your test_helper to invoke whatever you need invoked after testing is completed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great, have put the final thing as an answer

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to set my default task to run rubocop then the tests. Either way, it is a good idea to have those tasks separate rather than have one task do two things.

```
require 'rubocop/rake_task'

task :default => [:rubocop, :test]

desc 'Run tests'
task(:test) do
  # run your specs here
end

desc 'Run rubocop'
task :rubocop do
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new
end
```

Your tasks:

```
> rake -T
rake rubocop  # Run rubocop
rake test     # Run tests
```

Comment: how do I provide arguments to RuboCop?

Answer (score 3):

This is the .rake file that I ended up with in the end.

```
desc 'Run tests and rubocop'
task :validate do
  Rake::Task['rubocop'].invoke
  Rake::Task['test'].invoke
end

task :rubocop do
  require 'rubocop'
  cli = Rubocop::CLI.new
  cli.run(%w(--rails --auto-correct))
end
```

Comment: Could potentially also use this in a Thorfile then without all the Rake specifics.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to have changed from:

Rubocop::RakeTask.new

to:

Rubo**C**op::RakeTask.new

See ma?  I know how to CamelCase!

Answer (score 0):

I used following .rake file to run the test and rubocop tasks at once:

```
task default: %w[rubocop test]

RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:rubocop) do |task|
  task.patterns = ['**/*.rb']
  task.fail_on_error = false
  task.options = ["--auto-correct-all"]
end

task :test do
  ruby 'test/program_test.rb'
end
```

The first line allows both tasks to be run by calling `rake`.

Command line arguments can also be added in the `options` array.